# Adding item to DataGridView by clicking button using c#

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, datagridview, form-load

I'm writing a program for manage all customers we have in our company. I have a `DataGridView` where every single customer should display. And right to the `DataGridView` I got some textboxes, for displaying the details of every customer and for add a new customer. And I got a button "Add Customer". So if I type in some random text in textboxes and click on "Add Customer" it should add the new customer to the `DataGridView`. And if I restart the program, every customer should still be saved. So I save the details of every customer to a .xml file.

Can someone help me or give me a hint how I can add customers to `DataGridView` by clicking button? I got this code for saving to xml file:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        const string folder = @"C:\Users\Römel\Desktop\Save";
        const string basename = "save.xml";
        string filename = folder + "\\" + basename;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            if (Directory.Exists(folder))
            {
                if (File.Exists(filename))
                {
                    DataSet flatDataSet = new DataSet();
                    flatDataSet.ReadXml(filename);
                    DataTable table = flatDataSet.Tables[0];
                    dataGridKunden.DataSource = table;
                }

                dataGridKunden.Columns["KundenNr"].Visible = false;
                dataGridKunden.Columns["Adresse"].Visible = false;
                dataGridKunden.Columns["Ort"].Visible = false;
                dataGridKunden.Columns["Telefon"].Visible = false;
                dataGridKunden.Columns["Mail"].Visible = false;

                dataGridKunden.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.None;
            }
        }

        private void btnAddKunde_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(folder))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);
            }
            if (!File.Exists(filename))
            {
                File.Create(filename);
            }
            XmlTextWriter xwriter = new XmlTextWriter(filename, Encoding.Unicode);
            xwriter.WriteStartDocument();
            xwriter.WriteStartElement("Kundenverwaltung");
            xwriter.WriteStartElement("KundenNr");
            xwriter.WriteString(txtKundenNr.Text);
            xwriter.WriteEndElement();
            xwriter.WriteStartElement("Nachname");
            xwriter.WriteString(txtKundeNachname.Text);
            xwriter.WriteEndElement();
            xwriter.WriteStartElement("Vorname");
            xwriter.WriteString(txtKundeVorname.Text);
            xwriter.WriteEndElement();
            xwriter.WriteStartElement("Adresse");
            xwriter.WriteString(txtKundeAdresse.Text);
            xwriter.WriteEndElement();
            xwriter.WriteStartElement("Ort");
            xwriter.WriteString(txtKundeOrt.Text);
            xwriter.WriteEndElement();
            xwriter.WriteStartElement("Telefon");
            xwriter.WriteString(txtKundeTel.Text);
            xwriter.WriteEndElement();
            xwriter.WriteStartElement("Mail");
            xwriter.WriteString(txtKundeMail.Text);
            xwriter.WriteEndElement();
            xwriter.WriteEndDocument();
            xwriter.Close();
        }
    }
```

The button "Add Customer" is called "btnAddKunde".

Thanks in advance.

Cheers

Comment: I edited and changed the `@"\"` to `"\\"` to make the code below formatted correctly, looks like the `SO's parser` thinks the second double quote in `@"\"` is escaped by the \ without knowing about the affection of `@`.

Comment: Maybe I am going blind here but, where is the code to add items to the datagridview?

Comment: @Brian This is my question, I found a lot of code which doesn't help me. So I came here to ask if someone can give me a hint :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add These line of code in your button click event in last:

```
if (File.Exists(filename))
{
      DataSet flatDataSet = new DataSet();
      flatDataSet.ReadXml(filename);
      DataTable table = flatDataSet.Tables[0];
      dataGridKunden.DataSource = table;
}
```

However, your version of XmlTextWriter will overwrite the xml file. Thus, when you click on button you will see only the latest added row. Instead you can use below code in your button click event:

```
private void btnAddKunde_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(folder))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);
        }
        if (!File.Exists(filename))
        {
            using (File.Create(filename))
            {}
        }

        XElement xmlNode = new XElement("Kundenverwaltung",
                                        new XElement("KundenNr", txtKundenNr.Text),
                                        new XElement("Nachname", txtKundeNachname.Text),
                                        new XElement("Vorname", txtKundeVorname.Text),
                                        new XElement("Adresse", txtKundeAdresse.Text),
                                        new XElement("Ort", txtKundeOrt.Text),
                                        new XElement("Telefon", txtKundeTel.Text),
                                        new XElement("Mail", txtKundeMail.Text)
            );
        XElement xmlFile;
        try
        {
            xmlFile = XElement.Load(filename);
            xmlFile.Add(xmlNode);

        }
        catch (XmlException)
        {
            xmlFile = new XElement("Customers", xmlNode);
        }
        xmlFile.Save(filename);
        DataSet flatDataSet = new DataSet();
        flatDataSet.ReadXml(filename);
        DataTable table = flatDataSet.Tables[0];
        dataGridKunden.DataSource = table;
    }
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you. I got one more question. The new item which appears in `DataGridView` is shown if I click on "Add Customer" button. But if I restart the program, it doesn't load the existing items. I have to add a new item and then all other items are displayed. I tried `xmlFile = XElement.Load(filename); xmlFile.Add(xmlNode);` in `Form1_Load()` but I think thats wrong because it doesn't work. You know how?

Comment: Roman - For me it was working fine. If I restart the application then all saved records were shown. Make sure at load event all columns of DataGrid are visible.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use XMLDocument class to retrieve data from xml file

do something like this :

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("People.xml");

xmlDoc.Element("employee").Add(new XElement("Person", new XElement("Name", txtName.Text),
new XElement("City", txtCity.Text), new XElement("Age", txtAge.Text)));
```

Comment: So I can manage to add an item by clicking button with xmldocument? Do you have an example?

Comment: do you want to add a new Item or do you want to retrieve data and put it into datagrid?

Comment: I want to add an item do DataGridView if I'm clicking a button. This is my primary problem. If I could fix that, the program should be able to read the xml file by starting program so that all items still be here after a restart of the program. You know what I mean? :)

Comment: you mean to add a new element to xml file, then it has to appear in datagrid

Comment: Yeah that's what I mean. This should happen if I click on a button

Comment: Mh. It won't work. Maybe I did it wrong. It overrides the xml file. And it shouldn't override it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you lookin for an example for retrieving data from xml or just add string array retrieved from xml??

Here's how you add a string array..

```
string[] s = new string[4];
s[0] = "Salim";
s[1] = "9388938813"
s[2] = "s/10 santhi Nagar, Dpo road, Palakkad"
s[3] = "Kerala"
datagridView1.Rows.Add(s);
```

Comment: I want to add an item do DataGridView if I'm clicking a button. I got some textboxes and if I fill some text into the textboxes and click on a button, the text from textboxes should go to DataGridView (the textboxes are "surname", "forename" etc.). You understand? :)

Answer (score 0):

```
dataGridKunden.Rows.Add(new string[] {surname.text, forename.text, address.text .... });
// add as much as you want.
```

Comment: I will look at it tomorrow, because another error occured. But thank you. I will tell you more tomorrow evening :)